# Sound only in headphones

Tags: sound

I have no problem with sound when the headphones are connected.
However, I am getting no sound from the laptop speakers.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

<sub>(I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Asus N82JV.)</sub>

Comment: This may seems silly, but are the speakers plugged into a jack that works, and turned on?

Comment: when I mean the laptop speakers, I mean the internal laptop speakers, the ones that are incorporated in the laptop already.

Comment: Did they worked fine under another OS?

Comment: @jester yes. i have dual boot with windows 7 and they work with no problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you've tried adjusting the output device in the regular "Sound Settings" window?

If that doesn't work, I've always managed to resolve issues by using either `alsamixer` (you need to run that one in a terminal) or failing that [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/pavucontrol/).

Comment: i have done both things already.. that didn't fixed it

Answer (score -1):

And Update of the Bios solved the problem for me.